# SomersDelta function from DescTools

Tags: r, function, desctools

Using the function with default *direction* variable in R, what would be dependent value x or y if I write it just like it?:

```
 SomersDelta(x,y)
```

Comment: The docs suggest that the default direction is "row", which calculates Somers D (R|C). If you supply both an x and a y argument as vectors, this will be converted to `table(x, y)`. This means the levels of the x variable be in the _rows_. The docs also state that "R|C indicates that the column variable y is regarded as the independent variable and the row variable x is regarded as dependent". From this we can infer that the way you have called it makes x the dependent variable and y the independent.